# Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance

Tags: centos7, openstack, openstack-nova

Trying to make a proof of concept cloud by following this guide https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/

I managed to get OpenStack installed and I'm able to access the dashboard. When I go to make an instance, I get an error.

```
Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "oof", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance 4cc5781c-7977-48f4-b625-6bb19b5f51df.].
```

States something about exhausted hosts. A coworker of mine stated it may be related to not having virtualization extensions enabled, but I have the `vmx` flag when I do `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. Also completely new to OpenStack so I am not sure how else to troubleshoot this. Is this related to Nova? Should I not be jumping right into instance creation? I tried making a floating IP at first. That went ok. Lost...